# avoiding #error in textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have combobox in a main form and after update, my subform requeries and displays relevant records. My subform is a continuous form not datasheet, if that's relevant. I have a textbox in my main form which refers to the subform. It is currently set as the following:

```
=[Cat_Section_sub].[Form]![Code_Extension_syntax]
```

This works fine as long as there are records in my subform. However, when I load the form there aren't any records in my subform. So the textbox displays `#Error`. Is there anything that I can do, like the Nz function, that will help me avoid displaying this error? The `Nz` function didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [IsError](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IsError-Function-40a89200-138b-4e60-b254-34aea51b2e6b):

```
=IIf(Not IsError([Cat_Section_sub].[Form]![Code_Extension_syntax]),[Cat_Section_sub].[Form]![Code_Extension_syntax],0)
```

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks for the quick response.